# Why can recv() in the client program receive messages sent to the client after the client has invoked shutdown(sockfd, SHUT_RD)?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming, posix

From [POSIX.1-2008/2013 documentation of shutdown()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shutdown.html):

> `int shutdown(int socket, int how);`
>
> ...
>
> The `shutdown()` function shall cause all or part of a full-duplex
>   connection on the socket associated with the file descriptor socket to
>   be shut down.
>
> The `shutdown()` function takes the following arguments:
>
> - `socket`
>     Specifies the file descriptor of the socket.
> - `how`
>     Specifies the type of shutdown. The values are as follows:
>
>   - `SHUT_RD`
>       Disables further receive operations.
>   - `SHUT_WR`
>       Disables further send operations.
>   - `SHUT_RDWR`
>       Disables further send and receive operations.
>
> ...

The [manual page for
`shutdown(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shutdown.2.html)
says pretty much the same thing.

> The `shutdown()` call causes all or part of a full-duplex connection
>   on the socket associated with sockfd to be shut down. If `how` is
>   `SHUT_RD`, further receptions will be disallowed. If `how` is `SHUT_WR`,
>   further transmissions will be disallowed.  If `how` is `SHUT_RDWR`,
>   further receptions and transmissions will be disallowed.

But I think I am able to receive data even after a
`shutdown(sockfd, SHUT_RD)` call. Here is the test I orchestrated and
the results I observed.

```
------------------------------------------------------
Time  netcat (nc)  C (a.out)   Result Observed
------------------------------------------------------
 0 s  listen       -           -
 2 s               connect()   -
 4 s  send "aa"    -           -
 6 s  -            recv() #1   recv() #1 receives "aa"
 8 s  -            shutdown()  -
10 s  send "bb"    -           -
12 s  -            recv() #2   recv() #2 receives "bb"
14 s  -            recv() #3   recv() #3 returns 0
16 s  -            recv() #4   recv() #4 returns 0
18 s  send "cc"    -           -
20 s  -            recv() #5   recv() #5 receives "cc"
22 s  -            recv() #6   recv() #6 returns 0
------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is a brief description of the above table.

- **Time:** Time elapsed (in seconds) since the beginning of the test.
- **netcat (nc):** Steps performed via netcat (nc). Netcat was made to listen
  on port 8888 and accept TCP connections from my C program compiled to
  ./a.out. Netcat plays the role of the server here. It sends three
  messages "aa", "bb" and "cc" to the C program after 4s, 10s and 18s,
  respectively, have elapsed.
- **C (a.out):** Steps performed by my C program compiled to ./a.out. It
  performs 6 recv() calls after 6s, 12s, 14s, 16s, 20s and 22s have
  elapsed.
- **Result observed:** The result observed in the output of the C program.
  It shows that it is able to recv() the message "bb" that was sent
  after `shutdown()` completed successfully. See rows for "12 s" and
  "20 s".

Here is the C program (client program).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main()
{
    struct addrinfo hints, *ai;
    int sockfd;
    int ret;
    ssize_t bytes;
    char buffer[1024];

    /* Select TCP/IPv4 address only. */
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    if ((ret = getaddrinfo("localhost", "8888", &hints, &ai)) == -1) {
        printf("getaddrinfo() error: %s\n", gai_strerror(ret));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if ((sockfd = socket(ai->ai_family, ai->ai_socktype, ai->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
        printf("socket() error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Connect to localhost:8888. */
    sleep(2);
    if ((connect(sockfd, ai->ai_addr, ai->ai_addrlen)) == -1) {
        printf("connect() error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(ai);

    /* Test 1: Receive before shutdown. */
    sleep(4);
    bytes = recv(sockfd, buffer, 1024, 0);
    printf("recv() #1 returned %d bytes: %.*s\n", (int) bytes, (int) bytes, buffer);

    sleep(2);
    if (shutdown(sockfd, SHUT_RD) == -1) {
        printf("shutdown() error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("shutdown() complete\n");

    /* Test 2: Receive after shutdown. */
    sleep (4);
    bytes = recv(sockfd, buffer, 1024, 0);
    printf("recv() #2 returned %d bytes: %.*s\n", (int) bytes, (int) bytes, buffer);

    /* Test 3. */
    sleep (2);
    bytes = recv(sockfd, buffer, 1024, 0);
    printf("recv() #3 returned %d bytes: %.*s\n", (int) bytes, (int) bytes, buffer);

    /* Test 4. */
    sleep (2);
    bytes = recv(sockfd, buffer, 1024, 0);
    printf("recv() #4 returned %d bytes: %.*s\n", (int) bytes, (int) bytes, buffer);

    /* Test 5. */
    sleep (4);
    bytes = recv(sockfd, buffer, 1024, 0);
    printf("recv() #5 returned %d bytes: %.*s\n", (int) bytes, (int) bytes, buffer);

    /* Test 6. */
    sleep (2);
    bytes = recv(sockfd, buffer, 1024, 0);
    printf("recv() #6 returned %d bytes: %.*s\n", (int) bytes, (int) bytes, buffer);
}
```

The above code was saved in a file named `foo.c`.

Here is a tiny shell script that compiles and runs the above program and
invokes netcat (`nc`) to listen on port 8888 and respond to the client
with messages `aa`, `bb` and `cc` at specific intervals as per the table
shown above. The following shell script is saved in a file called
`run.sh`.

```sh
set -ex
gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L foo.c
./a.out &
(sleep 4; printf aa; sleep 6; printf bb; sleep 8; printf cc) | nc -vvlp 8888
```

When the above shell script is run, the following output is observed.

```
$ sh run.sh 
+ gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L foo.c
+ nc -vvlp 8888
+ sleep 4
listening on [any] 8888 ...
+ ./a.out
connect to [127.0.0.1] from localhost [127.0.0.1] 54208
+ printf aa
+ sleep 6
recv() #1 returned 2 bytes: aa
shutdown() complete
+ printf bb
+ sleep 8
recv() #2 returned 2 bytes: bb
recv() #3 returned 0 bytes: 
recv() #4 returned 0 bytes: 
+ printf cc
recv() #5 returned 2 bytes: cc
recv() #6 returned 0 bytes: 
 sent 6, rcvd 0
```

The output shows that the C program is able to receive messages with
`recv()` even after it has called `shutdown()`. The only behaviour that
the `shutdown()` call seems to have affected is whether the `recv()`
call returns immediately or gets blocked waiting for the next message.
Normally, before `shutdown()`, the `recv()` call would wait for a
message to arrive. But after the `shutdown()` call, `recv()` returns `0`
immediately when there is no new message.

I was expecting all `recv()` calls after `shutdown()` to fail in some way (say, 
return `-1`) due to the documentation I have quoted above.

Two questions:

1. Is the behaviour observed in my experiment, i.e. `recv()` call being
   able to receive new messages sent after `shutdown()` call correct as per
   the POSIX standard and the manual page for `shutdown(2)` that I have
   quoted above?
2. Why is it that after `shutdown()` is called, `recv()` returns `0` immediately instead of waiting for a new message to arrive?

Comment: This is the problem with documentation that is protocol neutral. It gives you no clue what that means for any particular protocol. People make this same mistake a lot with `select` when they forget that the documentation for `select` talks about read or write generically and doesn't explain what they mean for TCP specifically.

Comment: Because there was still pending unread data.

Comment: @EJP Could you please describe exactly what is considered 'pending unread data'? When the `shutdown()` call was my made in my code, there was no pending unread data. All data sent to it via netcat (`nc`) was already successfully received and printed by my C program. Then 2 seconds *after* the `shutdown()` call was made, *new* data was sent to the program via netcat and this new data was also successfully received by my program. This looks like new data to me, and therefore not pending unread data. Do you consider this new data as pending unread data? If so, why?

Comment: 'Unread data' is data you haven't read yet that arrived before the FIN or shutdown. However as you *now* state that the data was sent after `shutdown()` was called, clearly that isn't the explanation. But 'after the shutdown() call, recv() returns 0 immediately when there is no new message' is the correct behaviour. You have no basis for 'expecting all `recv()` calls after `shutdown()` to fail and return -1'. There is nothing in the 'documentation above' you quoted that supports that expectation. Nor is there any basis for expecting it to wait until a new message arrives as per your (2).

Comment: In fact your findings appear to be mututually contradictory. *Either* `recv()` returned zero immediately *or* it returned the new data sent after you called `shutdown()`. You can't have it both ways at the same time.

Comment: @EJP I see both the things happening under different conditions. The `recv()` call returns the new data after `shutdown()` when new data is sent between the `shutdown()` and `recv()`. After this new data is consumed and if no new data is sent, then a subsequent `recv()` call returns `0` immediately without blocking. If some new data is sent again and then another `recv()` call is made, it returns the new data again. I have illustrated this in the table I have included in my question (see the first code block in the question).

Comment: Please note that `shutdown` does not completely terminate the connection, it simply closes it to further read/write operations. If you want to make sure the socket is completely destroyed use `close`.

Comment: If `shutdown(sockfd, SHUT_RD)` indeed discarded all incoming data, what would you use it for?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin We could use it to only send data.

Comment: @SusamPal, 1) If you want to only send data, don't call `recv`. Job done. 2) If you want to discard/ignore incoming data, call `recv` and discard the data. Job done. 3) If you want the remote peer to get an `EPIPE` if they call `send`, bad luck. there is no way to do this in the `TCP` protocol. 4) There is no special definition of "pending", so the TCP protocol is free to interpret it broadly.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin You would use it to discard all incoming data, because that's what it does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You asked two questions: Is it compliant with the posix standard, and why does `recv` return 0 instead of blocking.

**Standard for shutdown**

The documentation for `shutdown` says:

> The shutdown() function disables subsequent send and/or receive operations on a socket, depending on the value of the how argument.

This appears to imply that no further `read` calls will return any data.

However the documention for `recv` states:

> If no messages are available to be received and the peer has performed an orderly shutdown, recv() shall return 0.

Reading these together this could mean that after the remote peer calls `shutdown`

1. calls to `recv` should return an error if data is available, or
2. calls to `recv` can continue to return data after `shutdown` if "messages are available to be received".

While this is somewhat ambiguous, the first interpretation does not make sense, as it's not clear what purpose an error would serve. Therefore the correct interpretation is the second.

(Note that any protocol which buffers at any point in the stack might have data in transit which cannot yet be read. The semantics of `shutdown` enable you to still receive this data after calling `shutdown`.)

*However this refers to the peer calling `shutdown`, rather than the calling process.* Should this also apply if the calling process called `shutdown`?

**So is it compliant or what**

The standard is ambiguous.

If a process calling  `shutdown(fd, SHUT_RD)` is to be considered equivalent to the *peer* calling `shutdown(fd, SHUT_WR)` then it is compliant.

On the other hand, reading the text strictly, it seems not to be compliant. But then there is no error code for the case where a process calls `recv` after `shutdown(SHUT_RD)`. The error codes are exhaustive, which implies that this scenario is not an error, so should return `0` as in the corresponding situation where the peer calls `shutdown(SHUT_WR)`.

Nevertheless, this is the behaviour you want - message in transit can be received if you want them. If you don't want to them don't call `recv`.

To the extent that this is ambiguous, it should be considered a bug in the standard.

**Why isn't post-`shutdown` `recv` data limited to data which was in transit**

In the general case it is not possible to know what data is in transit.

- In the case of unix sockets, data may be buffered on the receiving side, by the operating system, or on the sending side.
- In the case of TCP, data may be buffered by the receiving process, by the operating system, by the network card hardware buffer, packets may be in transit at intermediate routers, buffered by the sending network card hardware, by sending operating system or sending process.

**Background**

- posix provides an api for uniformly interacting with different types of streams, including anonymous pipes, named pipes, and IPv4 and IPv6 TCP and UDP sockets... and raw Ethernet, and Token Ring and IPX/SPX, and X.25 and ATM...
- Therefore posix provides a set of functionality which broadly covers the main capabilities of most streaming and packet-based protocols.
- However not every capability is supported by ever protocol

From a design point of view, if a caller requests an operation which is not supported by the underlying protocol, there are a number of options:

- Enter an error state, and forbid any further operations on the file descriptor.
- Return an error from the call, but otherwise disregard it.
- Return success, and do the nearest thing that makes sense.
- Implement some sort of wrapper or filler to provide the missing functionality.

The first two options are precluded by the posix standard. Clearly the third option has been chosen by Linux developers.

Comment: `shutdown()` syscall on a TCP socket is handled by `net/socket.c:sys_shutdown()` which calls `net/tcpv4/af_inet.c:inet_shutdown()` via the socket operations. `inet_shutdown()` modifies `how` so that the userspace `SHUT_RD`/`SHUT_WR`/`SHUT_RDWR` are mapped to `RCV_SHUTDOWN`/`SEND_SHUTDOWN`/`RCV_SHUTDOWN|SEND_SHUTDOWN`, respectively, before calling `net/ipv4/tcp.c:tcp_shutdown()` (via `sock->sk->sk_prot->shutdown`). So no, it is not wrong. But you are correct otherwise.

Comment: Note that by mapping, I meant [increased by one](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/ipv4/af_inet.c#n784), because that's what the code does: in userspace, `SHUT_RD=0`, `SHUT_WR=1`, `SHUT_RDWR=2`; but in kernel space, `RCV_SHUTDOWN=1` and `SEND_SHUTDOWN=2`. It is a real hacky way to do it, but at least there is a comment in the code (as to why it is done and why it works).

Comment: TCP does indeed support shutting down in one direction. This is called a 'half-close' in RFC 793.

Comment: I don't think you could say it isn't implemented for TCP either. There are various actions taken in tcp.c when `sk_shutdown` contains `RCV_SHUTDOWN`, for example exiting the read loop inside `tcp_splice_read`

Comment: There is nothing in your quotations about `recv()` returning an error. The behaviour when the peer has performed an orde,y shutdown is irrelevant to the behaviour when the local application has shutdown for reading.  Your case for the standard being ambiguous does not hold water.

Comment: @EJP According to the standard, what is the return value of `recv` if the process (not the peer) has called `shutdown(fd, SHUT_RD)`? It does not say. Suppose it is -1, what should `errno` be? There is no error number for this case. That's what makes it ambiguous, the standard simply does not cover this case at all.

Comment: If the current application has called `shutdown(fd, SHUT_RD)`, a subsequent or even a concurrent `recv()` should return zero once it has exhausted all the pending data. There is no reason for it to return -1. No error, no ambiguity. Zero when there is no more data.